# Regress values inside the bounding boxes to predict a value in Object Detection

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, regression

I am currently working on an object detection task. I have a dataset of Grayscale and Depth Images.  The annotation format is **x1, y1, x2, y2, class, depth**. I have calculated this depth (of each object/bounding box) using a clustering algorithm and depth image.

My plan is to use the Grayscale images to detect the bounding boxes and the class labels using a pre-trained CNN.

Furthermore, I want to use the depth images to predict the depth (ground truth values in the dataset as mentioned above). For this task, my plan is to build a Regression-based Neural Network that regresses the depth values inside the bounding boxes of the depth image and compares them to the ground truth values. An RMSE loss function can be used to keep track of the predictions.

How do I go about making this NN and is there a better alternative?

Comment: Hello. Could you please put your main **specific** question in the title to immediately give an idea of what this post is really about?

Comment: Hey @nbro , I am struggling to find the title. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nbro I have changed the title. Hopefully, I get some help now.